# How to change the theorem number?

Tags: numbering, amsmath, theorems, thmtools

I would like to change the number of theorem as in picture below to **Theorem 5.1** not 5.0.1 ( I want to get a rid of 0 )

[image]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]



\chapter{results}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{theorem}    
Theorem statment

.\end{theorem}
```

Comment: Obviously, the answer depends on the way you defined the numbering of theorems. Can you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) reproducing the problem?

Comment: I use \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]



\begin{theorem}          


                                                                                                                                                             \end{theorem}

Comment: Depending on the document class you use (for example), the code you provided might reproduce your problem or it might not. Why not providing a minimal working example?

Comment: The code you added to the question is still not a complete example that can be compiled to reproduce the problem: the `article` class does not have a `\chapter` command, and there is no `\end{document}`. I guess in your real document you should replace `section` with `chapter` in `\newtheorem`, but I can't be sure that it will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify your code as follows to be able to replicate the screenshot you posted:

```
\documentclass{book} % or: \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}  % or: \usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5} % just for this example
\begin{theorem} Theorem statement. \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that you don't have a `\section` command (which increments the `section` *counter*) before the `\begin{theorem}` directive.

I can think of two ways to fix this:

- Provide one or more `\section` directives within a given chapter *before* issuing the first instance of `\begin{theorem}`.
- Change `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` to `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`.